# I felt the (a?) sting of wounded pride

Tags: grammar

I'm uncertain about what article should I use in this sentence.
On the one hand, I think it's a specific type of sting (that is, of wounded pride) but on the other hand, it's "one of possible" stings so it might call for an indefinite article.
What's your take on these cases?

Comment: You've explained it well; either one could be used.

Comment: The definite article does not indicate that something is a specific type of _X_. It indicates that it is a specific _X_. More importantly, it indicates that the noun in question is already familiar in the current discourse. In this case, _the sting of wounded pride_ would imply that this is a sting that both the speaker and the listener are familiar with—it is a **known** sting, a familiar sting, a sting that you recognise when you hear it referred to.

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking of feeling the generic pain of wounded pride, use the definite article; if you're thinking of this particular instance of pain associated with wounded pride, then use the indefinite.